# Vitamio Not working @android app

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, vimeo, vitamio

I am trying to implement Vitamio lib for vimeo but it's always showing message that it can't play. Even I tried for youtube, it's not working because of the same error message.

```
     mVideoView.setVideoPath("//www.youtube.com/embed/Bp3i71jaWNo"); //or vimeo 
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                // optional need Vitamio 4.0
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
```

On logcat I can see this message:

```
avformat_open_input no such file or directory error (1, -2)
```

Or this one:

```
avformat_open_input i/o error -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for:

```
myVideoView.setVideoURI(URI.parse("http://mypathtovideo"));
```

Make sure you have the correct permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: ya i tired that also "http://player.vimeo.com/video/4104426" and permission is added

Comment: Did you tried `myVideoView.setVideoURI(URI.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/4104426"));` and got the same error?

Comment: by this , i am getting  error avformat_open_input i/o error -5

Comment: any other way to play vimeo video in app (apart from web-view)?

Comment: For youtube, it exists an api [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/). Maybe it could help you.

Comment: i want to implement  for vimeo video

Comment: Stackoverflow isnt a code provider. Look how to embed html on your app if you want more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
mVideoView.setVideoPath("//www.youtube.com/embed/Bp3i71jaWNo");
```

doesn't work because:

1.) "//www.youtube.com/embed/Bp3i71jaWNo" isn't a valid URL

and

2.) Even if you remove "//" this is a link to the page containing the specific video, not the video itself. In other words, it isn't a link to a valid stream.